# Can't delete and remove SELinux context or ACL from a symlink in /usr/lib under root

Tags: symlink, selinux, acl

I'm on Fedora 27 and experience problems with updating the packages by `dnf update`. The problem is exactly as described here: https://superuser.com/q/1005740/683161

I tried to delete symlink under `/usr/lib`, but can't, even under root:

```
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ sudo rm -f /usr/lib/cpp 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/cpp': Operation not permitted
...
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ file /usr/lib/cpp 
/usr/lib/cpp: symbolic link to ../bin/cpp
...
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ ls -al /usr/lib/cpp 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Sep 15 15:01 /usr/lib/cpp -> ../bin/cpp
```

I see that file has a dot at the end of file permissions. By googling I found commands to remove the SELinux context or ACL (I don't know what are those). But still can't fix it:

```
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ sudo setfacl -b /usr/lib/cpp
...
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ ls -al /usr/lib/cpp 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Sep 15 15:01 /usr/lib/cpp -> ../bin/cpp
... 
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ sudo rm -f /usr/lib/cpp 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/cpp': Operation not permitted
...
vplagov@thinkpad:~ $ sudo setfattr -x security.selinux /usr/lib/cpp 
setfattr: /usr/lib/cpp: Permission denied
```

Is there a "healthy" option to fix this?

Comment: Are there any related log entries in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?

Comment: Yes, there are. When I run `sudo setfattr -x security.selinux /usr/lib/cpp`, following logs to the audit.log: https://justpaste.it/1i2gc
But I can't quite understand the output of this log.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to relabel the files on your machine by running `fixfiles onboot` and then rebooting

You might also want to check in which context your current user is running with `id -Z`, on default installation, your user should run in `unconfined_t`.

`ls-z` shows the SeLinux labels (compare them to a „good“ system).

`setenforce 0` will disable SeLinux temporary, though you are better off fixing the root cause (broken SeLinux labels).

Answer (score 1):

**Reboot with "emergency shell".**

I think the fastest way could be to reboot the computer with SELinux enforcing mode disabled into an emergency shell.  Just pass "rd.break enforcing=0" to your kernel boot command line (append to the line starting with "linux " in you GRUB boot menu, then Ctrl+x to boot). After booting, remount the `/` partition read-write

```
mount –o remount,rw /sysroot
```

In this shell you can just `cd`  into `/sysroot/usr/lib/` and/or `rm` your symbolic link.

To exit, type

```
reboot
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about this before. I did this, I deleted the `/usr/bin/cpp` symlink. Rebooted back in Fedora as usual, checked that that symlink doesn't exist and run `dnf upgrade` again, but still the same error... Don't know what is possible to do with it now, except reinstalling the OS.

Comment: OK, so the method *did* succeed removing the link, but the upgrade still failed?

Comment: yes, exactly as you described.